# How to get bigger images from facebook graph response?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am getting graph responses from the required facebook page through the page id but the image in the posts of the conxerned page are small in size. I want to get a bigger image or increase the resolution of the image of the posts.
I am getting the url of the image in the post from the json object returned as response. The url is of this form:
https://fb-external...&w=130&h=130...cfs=1.
I want to change the width and height of the image. How should i obtain a larger image?